# Aplicação Chat Cliente-Servidor com Sockets não funciona

Tags: java, swing, socket, cliente-servidor

Estou a realizar um projecto e cheguei à parte da comunicação entre o servidor e o cliente e não consegui o output que pretendia (imagem output pretendido).

O objetivo é que o servidor e o cliente consigam comunicar entre si. Ou seja, para testar isto digito um utilizador e se carregar no botão online esse nome do utilizador aparece nas mensagens recebidas. Esse método não se encontra em anexo pois está bem feito.

O servidor não está a funcionar.

E alguém me explica esse NIMBUS (classe cliente) gerado pelo netbeans? Passei para Eclipse, é suposto ser assim?

[image: Output pretendido]

## CLASSE CLIENTE

```
public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new QuequeApp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Servidor

```
public class Servidor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SocketServidor socket_servidor = new SocketServidor();
    }
}
```

## SocketCliente

```
public class SocketCliente {
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;

    public Socket conectar(){   
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket("localHost", 8080); 
            this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return socket;
    }

    public void enviar(MensagensChat mensagem){
        try {
            output.writeObject(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

## SocketServidor

```
public class SocketServidor {
    private ServerSocket servidorSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> utilizadoresChat = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();  

    public SocketServidor(){
        try {
            servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while(true){                            
                socket = servidorSocket.accept();           
                new Thread(new ListennerSocket(socket)).start();    
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private class ListennerSocket implements Runnable {
        private ObjectOutputStream output;      
        private ObjectInputStream input;

        public ListennerSocket(Socket socket) {
            try {
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            MensagensChat mensagem = null;

            try {
                while((mensagem = (MensagensChat) input.readObject() )!= null){ 
                    Accao accao = mensagem.getAccao(); 
                    if(accao.equals(Accao.ONLINE)){
                        conectar(mensagem, output);
                    }else if(accao.equals(Accao.OFFLINE)){

                    }else if(accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_UM)){

                    }else if(accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_TODOS)){

                    }else if(accao.equals(Accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE)){

                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void conectar(MensagensChat mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output){   
            enviar_para_um(mensagem, output);
        }

        private void enviar_para_um(MensagensChat mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output){
            try {
                output.writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe MensagensChat

```
public class MensagensChat implements Serializable {

private String nome;            
private String mensagem;    
private String nomeClienteReceptorMensagem;     
private Set<String> contactosOnline = new HashSet<String>();    
private Accao accao;                                


public String getNomeCliente() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNomeCliente(String nomeCliente) {
    this.nome = nomeCliente;
}
public String getTextoMensagem() {
    return mensagem;
}
public void setTextoMensagem(String textoMensagem) {
    this.mensagem = textoMensagem;
}
public String getNomeClienteMensagemReservada() {
    return nomeClienteReceptorMensagem;
}
public void setNomeClienteMensagemReservada(String nomeClienteMensagemReservada) {
    this.nomeClienteReceptorMensagem = nomeClienteMensagemReservada;
}
public Set<String> getContactosOnline() {
    return contactosOnline;
}
public void setContactosOnline(Set<String> contactosOnline) {
    this.contactosOnline = contactosOnline;
}
public Accao getAccao() {
    return accao;
}
public void setAccao(Accao accao) {
    this.accao = accao;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nimbus Look & Feel

O [Nimbus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) é uma implementação visual de interface de usuário (UI) multiplataforma incluída no Java 6.

É para ser uma evolução aos temas já existentes no Swing e realmente é mais bonitinho que os demais, além de apresentar melhor resolução por ser baseado em vetores e não em bitmaps.

O código com o *loop* no método `main` da classe `Cliente`, itera sobre os temas existentes no Java e, se o Nimbus estiver disponível, tenta ativá-lo no programa atual. Parece estranho, mas isso evita algum erro inesperado se o tema não estiver presente na versão do Java que está executando. Essa técnica aparece de forma variada, mas é um tipo de convenção comumente usado, independente de usar uma IDE ou não.

## Cliente - Servidor

Fiz o trabalho arqueológico de reconstituir algumas classes que não foram postadas. Não sei exatamente o código que você tem na tela, mas parece que está simplesmente faltando o método para ler o retorno.

Por exemplo, não vi em nenhum lugar onde você pega a resposta do servidor. Por exemplo:

```
this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

E depois:

```
public MensagensChat ler() {
    try {
        return (MensagensChat) input.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

## Código que funciona

O código abaixo foi modificado da pergunta e testado com sucesso. Note que é preciso executar o servidor primeiro e depois a classe cliente.

### Cliente

```
public class SocketCliente {
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;

    public Socket conectar() {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket("localHost", 8080);
            this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return socket;
    }

    public void enviar(MensagensChat mensagem) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MensagensChat ler() {
        try {
            return (MensagensChat) input.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SocketCliente cliente = new SocketCliente();
        cliente.conectar();
        cliente.enviar(new MensagensChat(Accao.ONLINE, "eu mesmo"));
        MensagensChat retorno = cliente.ler();
        System.out.printf(retorno.getMensagem());


    }
}
```

## Servidor

```
public class SocketServidor {
    private ServerSocket servidorSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> utilizadoresChat = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();

    public SocketServidor() {
        try {
            servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
            while (true) {
                socket = servidorSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new ListennerSocket(socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ListennerSocket implements Runnable {
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private ObjectInputStream input;

        public ListennerSocket(Socket socket) {
            try {
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            MensagensChat mensagem = null;

            try {
                while ((mensagem = (MensagensChat) input.readObject()) != null) {
                    Accao accao = mensagem.getAccao();
                    if (accao.equals(Accao.ONLINE)) {
                        conectar(mensagem, output);
                    } else if (accao.equals(Accao.OFFLINE)) {

                    } else if (accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_UM)) {

                    } else if (accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_TODOS)) {

                    } else if (accao.equals(Accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE)) {

                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void conectar(MensagensChat mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output) {
            enviar_para_um(mensagem, output);
        }

        private void enviar_para_um(MensagensChat mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SocketServidor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Essas classes que me enviou se as modificar fico com o problema resolvido?

Comment: Adicionei também aqui a minha classe MensagemChat. É que a mim da me erros na classe Cliente implementada por voce! Obrigado

Comment: Se voce fizer o import da minha classe MensagemChat e ver o construtor da me erros porque?

Comment: adicionei mais uma classe, é que com a solução isso da me erro em vários pontos e não estou mesmo a encontrar a solução pode me ajudar sff? Não me esta mesmo a dar o output pretendido

Comment: Outra duvida que tenho é com a sua solução, eu corro o servidor e depois o cliente, então para que tenho os mains nas classes socketClient e socketServidor